# Cannot push to github repo after cloning from remote repo

Tags: git, clone

1. Need to 'copy' a git repo from a remote repo in github ('original'
2. After I make my changes, I have to push it to my own rep on github
3. Need to provide the URL to my repo for evaluation.
4. I used 'git clone remote_URL' to create a local repo
5. On github I created an empty repo
6. I made the changes, did the add, commit
7. I need to push mu local repo to my remote repo
8. If I do 'git push origin master' it tries to push it to the 'original' repo

I need help to understand what the correct procedure is. Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

You should fork the the original remote repo into your own github account.  This essentially makes a copy of the repo and puts it into your github.  Then when you clone, just clone your forked repo.